# United Airlines domestic travel noise cancelling headphones carry on

Tags: usa, hand-luggage, united-airlines

Are noise cancelling headphones allowed for domestic travel on United flights? I am specifically wondering about [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A4A3SNW) ones.

Comment: That's the primary use case for noise cancelling headphones and how they came to be so popular. So yes, they are allowed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certainly. Headphones of all types are extremely common carry-on items, including noise cancelling models. They are permitted.

[United's electronic device policy](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/inflight/devices.aspx) not only doesn't prohibit headphones; it recommends them:

> As a courtesy to other travelers, please use headphones when listening
>   to any device.

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning that on aircraft equipped with entertainment, United uses standard 3.5mm headphone jacks, so you should not need an adapter to plug your own headphones in.

Comment: In some countries (e.g. Canada) you couldn't use these headphones until cruising altitude is reached, and only until about mid-descent.  During ascent and descent, Canada only allows in-ear bud-style headphones connected to the aircraft's entertainment system.  Once at cruising altitude, of course, you'd be fine.  The US seems more relaxed about this.